# REACT How to render a different image for the hero image based on URL

Tags: reactjs

I have been looking around and can't seem to figure this out. I have been getting fairly comfortable with React, but I feel like I am missing something. I have a homepage component, and an about page component, and a Reroimage component. I want the hero image to render the homepage.jpg on the / page. And I want to render the Aboutpage.jpg for the /about URL.

I thought I could simply pass props. I have the homepage image working, but not the Aboutpage image using the same method.

in the heroimage component, I  have
`<img src={props.img} />` 
and in each component for the pages, I have `<HeroImage img={homepage} />`  (importing jpg)
then in app.js I render the Homepage and About page under the  block and under each  etc

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

export const HeroImage = (props) => {
  return (
    <HeroImageContainer>
      <HeroImageWrapper>

        <img src={props.img} />

      </HeroImageWrapper>
    </HeroImageContainer>
  );
};
```

playing with some styled components as well.

```
import HeroImage from '../HeroImage'
import homepage from '../../assets/HomePage.jpg'


export const HomePage = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <HeroImage  img={homepage} />
        </div>
    )
}
```

```
function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/about">About</Link>
            </li>
            <li>
              <Link to="/userdashboard">Users</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

        {/* A <Switch> looks through its children <Route>s and
            renders the first one that matches the current URL. */}
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/">
            <HomePage />
             
            
          </Route>

          <Route exact path="/about">
            <About />
            

          </Route>

          <Route path="/userdashboard">
            <UserDashboard />
          </Route>

        </Switch>

      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please share the implementation of the About component too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could understand from your code, your `<Route path="/">` is matching on every other route. This means your `<HomePage />` component will be rendered regardless of any URL path you provide to other routes.

You need to be careful about `path` in `<Route>` components as the `path="/"` will match all the other paths that contain `/`, like in your `/about`, and in turn will render whatever is on `path="/"`.

This applies to any other strings that are substrings of other paths like `path="/about"` and `path="/about/something/else"`, `/about` will be matched and rendered on `/about/something/else` if you do not pass `exact` to `/about`.

From the [react-router docs](https://reactrouter.com/core/api/Route/path-string-string):

> `path`: `string` | `string[]`
> Any valid URL path or array of paths that `path-to-regexp@^1.7.0` understands.

and

> `exact`: `bool` When true, will only match if the path matches the
> location.pathname exactly.

So in your case you only have to add the `exact` prop to your `<Route path="/">` like so `<Route exact path="/">` and there's probably no need to pass `exact` in your `/about` route.

Here's a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-cookies-refz3?file=/src/App.js) using your code with some tweaks.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I intend to spend some time looking at this to learn from where I was making my mistake. I am happy to see I was somewhat on the right track in some areas. 
I really appreciate it. Hopefully soon I can be the one on the other end answering some questions to haha.

Comment: @LeBlancCode Glad you learned something! I've only just started web development and I figured that answering things that I already know will further boost my learning pace as it challenges all my current understanding. Don't worry and just keep practicing, you'll certainly get there too!

Comment: I absolutely did. I just marked your answer as correct as I just got it working correctly. You did a great job in your explanation as well. And looking at your codesandbox was extremely helpful. I knew I was missing something. I think I will join you soon and start answering some small things that I know. I think you're right that it will help challenge you and improve your knowledge. Thanks again, and I'll keep at it for sure ! Good luck to you as well.